# How to inject an EJB in Vaadin 7 for Usage in CustomComponent?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, vaadin, code-injection

I use the following:

- Eclipse Java EE Juno
- GlassFish 3.1.2,
- DerbyDB,
- JPA,
- EclipseLink and
- Vaadin 7.1.1.

Besides, I am new to Glassfish, DerbyDB, JPA, EcliseLink and Vaadin :-)
So please correct me if I'm wrong!

---

First of all: 
Please note that there are several [examples using the `Application` class](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding%20JPA%20to%20the%20Address%20Book%20Demo), but as this is about Vaadin 6, it is not capable for me.

I want to persist an entity `Member` in a Derby DB using JPA, but I'm having trouble doing that for two days now. What I try to do is to inject a stateless EJB `MemberManagerBean`, which has an `EntityManager` to manage the entity `Member`, anywhere in the Vaadin `UI` to use it inside of a `CustomComponent` to create a layout.

```
package de.ves.beans.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
public class Member implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "OPTLOCK")
    private Long version;

    protected String name;

    public Member(){}

    // getters and setters ...

}
```

---

```
package de.ves.beans.mgm;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import de.ves.beans.entities.Member;

@Stateless
public class MemberManagerBean implements MemberManagerLocal {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Member getMember(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Member.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public Member saveMember(Member member) {
        if (member.getId() == null){
            entityManager.persist(member);
        }else{
            entityManager.merge(member);
        }
        return member;
    }

}
```

---

```
package de.ves.beans.mgm;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;

import de.ves.beans.entities.Member;

@TransactionAttribute
@Local
public interface MemberManagerLocal {

    public Member getMember(Long id);

    public Member saveMember(Member member);

}
```

---

```
package de.ves.ui;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Title;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;

import de.ves.beans.mgm.MemberManagerBean;
import de.ves.club.Friends;
import de.ves.club.Members;
import de.ves.club.News;
import de.ves.contact.About;
import de.ves.home.Home;
import de.ves.media.Pics;
import de.ves.media.Videos;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("ves")
public class VesUI extends UI {

    private Navigator navigator;

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = VesUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {

    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        navigator = new Navigator(this, this);

        // Home

        MainLayout main = new MainLayout();
        main.setMiddle(new Home());
        navigator.addView(Home.PATH, main); 

        // ErrorView

        navigator.setErrorView(main);

        // Subpages

        main = new MainLayout();
        main.setMiddle(new Members());
        navigator.addView(Members.PATH, main);

                    // ...

    }

}
```

---

```
package de.ves.club;

import com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainer;
import com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainerFactory;
import com.vaadin.annotations.AutoGenerated;
import com.vaadin.server.FileResource;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.ContentMode;
import com.vaadin.ui.Alignment;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import de.ves.beans.entities.Member;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Members extends CustomComponent {


            // Components and stuff...


    public Members() {
        buildMainLayout();
        setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);

        pnl_root.setSizeFull();

        // Several inits...

                    // This is where I want to read/write from/into the DB.
                    // This is not possible since I can't access the 
                    // MemberManagerBean. The following code shows my approach
                    // concering with a JPAContainer.

        JPAContainer<Member> members = JPAContainerFactory.make(Member.class, "vesPersistence");
        Member m = new Member();
        members.addEntity(m);

    }

    @AutoGenerated
    private VerticalLayout buildMainLayout() {
        // ...
    }

            // ...

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="vesPersistence">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>de.ves.beans.entities.Member</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ves;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="..." />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

My first approach was to injecting an EJB in a `CustomComponent`...

```
    @EJB
    private MemberManagerBean memberManager;
```

... but this results in a `NullPointerException`.

I read that injection works only in a `Servlet`. (Is this right?)

---

Now, the problem is that, unlike in a common DWP, in a Vaadin Project (in MY Vaadin Project) there is only one `Servlet`, which is a static class in the `UI`. Navigation inside the application occurs via a `Navigator`, other `Servlets` are unnecessary. Although injection in a static `Servlet` felt wrong to me, I tried that approach. And again, `NullPointerException`.

---

Third approach: Make usage of a `JPAContainer`, as stated [on vaadin.com](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/jpacontainer.html). This was nearly working but triggered a `ServletException`. See the code in the `Members` class.

It triggered the following:

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.

I can't explain why this comes up.

---

My last approach was to follow [this forum thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1938682), but it also resulted in a `NullPointerException`. Besides, I don't really want to use it since it seems to be a workaround.

---

I'd love to use the `JPAContainer`, but a common, regular way of using JPA within Vaadin would help indeed.

That's it. Can you help me please :-) Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `@EJB private MemberManagerBean memberManager;` Have you tried to access bean through local interface? Like: `@EJB private MemberManagerLocal memberManager;` The main point is to separate clients from implementation. Client code is not supposed to have access to actual beans.

Comment: Hi, I tried it right now inside of the `CustomComponent`. It didn't work.

Comment: Is there a JNDI entry for `MemberManagerLocal`? Usually glassfish create log records for new JNDI entries. You can use `asadmin list-jndi-entries` to be sure.

Comment: I tried it inside the workaround `Servlet` too. Didn't work as well.

Comment: $ /opt/glassfish/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-jndi-entries
jdbc: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
UserTransaction: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionNamingProxy$UserTransactionProxy
ejb: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
java:global: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl
Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.

Comment: But the GlassFish output while bootstrapping is: INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB MemberManagerBean: [java:global/VesEAR/VesWeb/MemberManagerBean, java:global/VesEAR/VesWeb/MemberManagerBean!de.ves.beans.mgm.MemberManagerLocal]

Comment: If you have several domains you'll need to specify admin port for `asadmin` command. Like: `asadmin -p 4949`. By default it returns results for port 4848.

Comment: I have only one domain. Admin port is 4848.

Comment: Have you tried setting `eclipselink.logging.level` to `FINE`?

Comment: No. Please give me some time I'm currently recreating the whole project to set up [Vaadin-CDI-integration](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin-CDI-integration).

Comment: Furthermore, have you studied this demo application for JPAContainers? http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/svn/addons/JPAContainer/trunk/jpacontainer-addressbook-demo/src/main?order=name#java/com/vaadin/demo/jpaaddressbook

Comment: Not this one. There is a related example for Vaadin 6 as I wrote above. This seems to be the same example based upon Vaadin 7. Give me some time to have a look at it. I'm still working on CDI-Integration, which works not as desired.

Comment: Ok, Vaadin-CDI-integration fails. An `Exception` is triggered, which is a [problem, which seems to be currently unsolved](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1101195). Now I will have a look at the Vaadin 7 JPAContainer demo.

Comment: Actually it is the demo for Vaadin 6 since the `AddressBookApplication` extends `Application`. I haven't realized this earlier. Thus not capable for Vaadin 7.

Comment: [Vaadin-CDI-integration UPDATE] The mentioned problem doesn't occur if the `?restartApplication` parameter is not set. As this is not desired in production mode anyway and everything else fails, I'll keep on trying to get a successful injection this way.